# Restart playframework automatically when it crashes with an exception

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Is there a way to restart playframework when it crashes with an exception?

I understand that it shouldn't crash. However, there might be an unexpected situation which causes the app to crash. So here we need a way to restart the playframework.

Answer (score 1):

Programming wise, well you rerun the app again, either through a command line or a script that check if the app is running. However I have an issue with the architecture here; which I would like to discuss.

The problem here I see is that you want to force a JVM based app to restart when it crashes with an exception, which is a serious flaw, in my book. Here is why:

**Ignoring the problem**: Why do you want to ignore the exception? Exceptions does not just pop-up; lets say in play app, I want to do an operation on an empty list that throws an exception; I better re-design my app; so that that crash does not occur. So I would suggest to know the nature of your exceptions before you put your app into production.

**Where are the tests?** Also does your tests capture the problem before it occurs, I hope you are not putting your app into production without any tests.

**I might be wrong here... Building Environment**: Ok if I give you the benefit of the doubt and now we assume that, you do test your app, and the exception is environment based (not related to your app) which makes your app to crash; then I would suggest to run your application on a container orchestration environment such as `Kubernetes` which does restart your app automatically; when it crashes.